# Соединение с БД через psql

Tags: psql

Почему при соединении с БД psql запрашивает пароль. Как можно этого избежать, не прописывая пароли в файле или пременных среды окружения?

Comment: где именно запрашивает пароль? В консоли можно `sudo -u postgres psql` написать))

Comment: Соединяюсь из под винды: psql postgres postgres Получаю: "Пароль пользователя postgres:". Пробовал задавать -w не помогло